# Can I benefit from more than one celerity effect in the same round?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, immediate-actions, daze

- Assuming I'm immune to daze (*quick recovery* does not work it seems, so any other way then like *Mark of the Dauntless*)
- I    resist it after doing my standard action acquired via *celerity*
  that I    just cast (**at the end of my turn so using the swift action from next turn)**
- If I have a *contingency*(*celerity*) with the condition: **If I    resist
  the daze effect directly after using *celerity* and there's    still a
  threat around me: activate** (or just **if I resist the daze    effect
  directly after casting *celerity*: activate** if the threat criteria is too vague for the DM, could waste it this way but oh well it's already OP as it is).

  - That would give me another standard action right?
- The immediate action (swift action of next round) is:  casting the spell *celerity* (wich would had been used in
     advance with    *contingency*) not having the actual benefit (standard action) from it right? and *contingency*(*Celerity*) should work Am-I right?
- I know about contingent items with *celerity* loops, but is that
  really legal? I would ban this of course, but I guess I would allow
  two *celerity* benefits in one round if the *contingency* was well prepared in
  advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before this is done at the table, talk to the DM and the other players. Be up front about what's going to happen: the character will, often during each encounter, be taking up to four standard actions pretty much *in a row.* First, the DM must be made aware of this so that she can account for creatures doing this. (Typically, what the PCs do the DM can also do, and the campaign setting may not have been designed with this in mind.) Second, the other players should be made aware that the character will be taking up a lot of game time. The other players should be prepared beforehand for their characters to be inconsequential for upwards of 20 min. while the DM adjudicates the character's multiple actions. Neither prospect may sit well. Abstractly and mechanically, taking a bunch of extra actions is awesome, but concretely and socially? Perhaps not so much.

## Confirmation: A step-by-step example of one possible sequence

In the morning, a caster casts the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***contingency***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#contingency) [evoc] (*Player's Handbook* 213), picks as the companion spell the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***celerity*** [trans] (*Player's Handbook II* 105), and picks as a condition something like *Upon resolving the action granted by the second* celerity *spell that I cast in a round beginning on my turn*. (A player can pick almost anything as a *contingency* spell's condition, but the DM determines if the condition is appropriate; see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27901/8610).)

Later, during an encounter, on her turn the caster takes a standard action to cast a spell, takes a move action to move up to her speed, then takes a swift action to cast a *celerity* spell ("Using an immediate action on your turn counts as your swift action for that turn" (*Rules Compendium* 7)). She then takes the granted standard action as if she had readied an action. Normally, at the conclusion of this last action, the caster would gain the condition dazed (*Player's Handbook* 307), but the caster is immune to this condition. (N.b. Gaining immunity to the dazed condition tends to be resource-intensive.)  Then her turn ends, and it's the next creature's turn.

At this point, a prescriptive reading of the *celerity* spell would limit the spell to being cast in response to a DM-approved stimulus because the standard action granted by the *celerity* spell is as if the caster had readied an action. However, a descriptive reading of the *celerity* spell—that reads its reference to the ready action as a comparison—allows the caster to cast to cast the *celerity* spell pretty much whenever, ready action trigger be damned. Either way, shortly after taking her second standard action the caster takes an immediate action to cast another *celerity* spell and takes this round her third standard action—this one, too, as if she had readied an action. (Taking an immediate action this way to cast this *celerity* spell—her second in the round that began with her turn—exhausts her next turn's swift action.)

Then, when that granted action is resolved, the *contingency* spell's condition is met, and the *contingency* spell's companion *celerity* spell is cast. The caster takes *another* standard action—her fourth this round—as if she had readied an action.

> #### Summary
>
> This sequence is complicated enough to warrant a summary. This summary is meant to supplement rather than replace the text above; refer to that text for details.
>
> 1. Gain immunity to dazed.
> 2. Before an encounter, cast *contingency*, picking *celerity* as the companion spell and picking ***Upon resolving the action granted by the second* celerity *spell that I cast in a round beginning on my turn*** as the condition.
> 3. During an encounter, take your turn normally except for your swift action.
> 4. Take your swift action to cast *celerity*.
> 5. Take a standard action. End your turn.
> 6. Take an immediate action to cast *celerity* again.
> 7. Take another standard action.
> 8. The companion *celerity* is cast is because the *contingency* condition's met. (This is not an action.)
> 9. Take another standard action.
> 10. It's now another creature's turn.

---

***Note:** The* Lords of Madness feat Quick Recovery *(181) is no help in resisting the dazed condition when chaining* celerity *spells: It's benefit kicks in specifically at the beginning of a creature's turn. What's needed is the* Dragonmarked *feat Mark of the Dauntless (142), but its prerequisite of a true dragonmark might make it unavailable in some campaigns. Further, while this DM doesn't require that real-world language be used in* contingency *spell conditions, comments make it clear that some DMs do. This sequence is likely much more difficult to employ if a* contingency *spell's condition must be mechanics-free.*

Comment: Awesome answer, however Quick Recovery states: Whenever you begin your turn stunned or dazed, you can make a **new saving throw** at the original DC of the effect that stunned or dazed you in an attempt to recover. Recovering from being stunned or dazed in this way is a move action, **if the effect that caused you to become stunned or dazed did not allow a saving throw, you can recover by succeeding on a Will save**.  wouldn't that mean that since you can't normally make a saving throw, you can just make one now and IF you fail you can do it again at the start of your turn?

Comment: Or that you can do it, even if it was not allowed at first.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier Thank you. O, and I know what the feat Quick Recovery says, but it doesn't come into play until the creature *begins its turn* (n.b. not its *action*) being stunned or dazed. *Then* the creature can make a new saving throw or a Will saving throw, success meaning that condition ends and the creature loses for that turn a move action.

Comment: Ok mark of the dauntless then, I play a silverbrow human, so it is totally justified to have a dragonmark in the campaign, I'll have to read about the houses/races and stuff, and it takes only one additionnal feat, I was supposed to take quick recovery in conjuction with force of personality, I'll just take least dragonmark and mark of the dauntless then (a least dragonmark is a True dragonmark). thank you  Someone else suggested this earlier too but deleted his comment, thanks again if you ever read this.

Comment: I like your example but as for my character instead of using celerity as my swift action on the first turn, I'll probably (when I can) use arcane spellsurge instead to cast 2 spells (metamagic and one normal or metamagic specialist etc.) then at the end of the round I'd use celerity if necessary (next swift action) then contingency Celerity. But reading all this, I'll nerf celerity to be usable only once in a round (or even one per combat) and that way even if' I'd contingent one, it would not work, being immuned to daze seems more balanced that way instead of baning that immunity.